# GridView getMeauredHeight() or getHeight() gives 0

Tags: android, gridview, height

I want to make number of rows in Gridview dynamic depending upon the screen size of the android phone. so i need height of the Gridview in onCreate() to count number of rows.(height / colums) here is a code snippet::

```
public class GridActivity extends Activity
{
     GridView gridView;
     GridAdapter adapter;'

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance state)
     {
          setContentView(R.layout.gridview);
          gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

          adapter = new GridAdapter(this);
          gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

          int gridHeight = gridView.getMeasuredHeight();
          Log.d("tag"," height :: " + gridHeight);
     }
 }
```

In log cat it shows -- height :: 0
I don't understand y it gives zero after properly inflating.

Is this a bug? Or I am missing something?

Comment: you find out screan height and width.

Comment: Screen height and width are not relevant here.question revolves around gridview's height only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridView would return 0 measuredheight and 0 height unless it is drawn to window, so you can not get height of GridVIew at the point, A workaround of your problem may be:
Add your Nth view to gridView by comparing total height of device with height of GridView occupied after n-1 views has been drawn to screen.

```
public void addNCompareHeight(View view)
 {   
    ViewTreeObserver observer = grid.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //in here, place the code that requires you to know the dimensions.
            //this will be called as the layout is finished, prior to displaying.
            if(gridHeight<requiredHeight)
            {
                 grid.addView(view);
                 addNCompareHeight(next);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think last part of your answer is missing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are going to relate your mobile screen size and GridView heigth. But here are the codes for finding out Screen resolution and GridView height.

1)To Find screen resolution do this in your onCreate(),

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int screen_width = dm.widthPixels;
    int screen_height = dm.heightPixels;
```

2)To find gridView height you can use the below method,

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{ 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     System.out.println("...111Height..."+gridview.getMeasuredWidth()); 
}
```

Comment: @AndroSelva Is `gridview.getMeasuredWidth()` in pixels?